# Determine the polarities of a self polar triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

Consider a triangle $PQR$, $P(0,2,1), Q(1,0,2), R(0,4,9)$. Determined the polarities if triangle $PQR$ is self polar.

By definition of self polar triangle, point $P$ gets mapped to line $QR$, point $Q$ gets mapped to line $PR$, and point $R$ gets mapped to line $PQ$.

Equation of $QR; 8x_1+9x_2-4x_3=0$

Equation of $PR; x_1=0$

Equation of $PQ; 4x_1+x_2-2x_3=0$

We have that $(0,2,1)$ gets mapped to $(8,9,-4)$, $(1,0,2)$ gets mapped to $(1,0,0)$, $(0,4,9)$ gets mapped to $(4,1,-2)$. But I cannot find any polarities because the determinant of the matrix of the polarity becomes 0. In that case, some points are singular points. But how do I know which points are singular??

Singular points are defined by to $P^tC=0$, where $C$ is the matrix of the polarity. But I don’t even have the matrix of the polarity... how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure why you think that there’s anything singular here. The polarity constraints are captured by the matrix equation $$C \begin{bmatrix} P & Q & R \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} s_P l_{QR} & s_Q l_{RP} & s_R l_{PQ} \end{bmatrix} \tag 1$$ with $s_i\ne0$ and $l_\alpha$ homogeneous coordinate vector representations of the lines, from which $$C = \begin{bmatrix} s_P l_{QR} & s_Q l_{RP} & s_R l_{PQ} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} P & Q & R \end{bmatrix}^{-1}.\tag 2$$ The three point coordinate vectors are obviously linearly independent, so the matrix on the right is invertible.

The three scalars $s_\alpha$ are indeterminate. Each unique set of ratios $s_P:s_Q:s_R$ generates a distinct polarity for which $\triangle{PQR}$ is self-polar. Since they must be nonzero, you can fix one of them at $1$ to get a two-parameter family of conics. The matrix $C$ is not unique (even up to scale) because the three polarity constraints are not independent, so are not in general sufficient to determine a unique conic.

Comment: I agree with you on this. But it is given to be $s_1 l_{QR} = CP$. Similar to the rest, there should be a scalar to it. Hence if I were to do it individually, the question is I cannot find any such scalars for $s_1$ and $s_3$, where $s_3 l_{PQ} = CR$

Comment: Furthermore, if it is a self polar triangle, it must be that it is a diagonal matrix, am I right to say that?

Comment: @Icycarus Those scalars are mostly irrelevant scale factors. If you compute the lines via cross products as I did, it turns out that they’re all equal to $1$. Note, too, that since you’re working in the projective plane, the condition $s_1l_{QR}=CP$ is equivalent to $l_{QR}\times(CP)=0$. As to your second point, the matrix of a polarity is not necessarily diagonal, but it is symmetric, as it also represents a quadric (conic in the plane). You can find a basis in which the matrix is symmetric, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! I will investigate further using your suggestions! However, I thought that the matrix of a polarity should be diagonal since it is a self polar triangle (I do understand that the matrix of polarity should be symmetric, but in this particular case, it should be diagonal, am I right(?) I might have misunderstood some concepts so just hoping to clear any misconceptions that I might have :))

Comment: @Icycarus No. There’s no particular reason to expect that the matrix will be diagonal, and it’s evident that it can’t be for this triangle: Its effect is to multiply each coordinate by a fixed scalar, but there’s nothing that you can multiply $0$ by to get $8$.

Comment: Interestingly, another way to generate $C$ is by taking linear combinations of the degenerate conics formed pairwise from the three lines.